# My js code does not work as expected unless i use an alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have an input field :

```
    <input class="quantityInput" data-index="@table.Rows.IndexOf(row)"
 type="number" value="@row[col.ColumnName]" min="1"/>
```

here is my js code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('change', '.quantityInput', function () {
            var data = {
                Id: $(this).data('index'),
                value: $(this).val()
            };
            $.getJSON("/Order/BasketSession/", data, function (result) { });
            location.reload(true);
            alert("hi!");
        });
    });
```

in my controller:

```
public JsonResult BasketSession(int Id, int value)
        {
            (HttpContext.Session["basket"] as DataTable).Rows[Id][2] = value;

            return Json(true);
        }
```

if i don't use `alert`, my `json` func does not wok when i change value of input field using keybord but with mouse click increase or decrease one by one it works either if i use `alert` or not(in chrome)

in firefox it doesn't work at all

i hope you could understand my problem

Comment: ajax isn't instant. you have to give it time to complete before you reload.

Comment: If you want to wait to execute the reload till after the ajax call put the code in the body of the success function handler.

Comment: but if don't use alert, break point at func doesn't hit

Comment: Have you moved the reload into the body of the success handler?  Otherwise as @Kevin B stated, the reload will likely occur before the ajax call has returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is worked for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('change', '.quantityInput', function () {
            var data = {
                Id: $(this).data('index'),
                value: $(this).val()
            };
            var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/Order/BasketSession/", data, function () { });
            jqxhr.complete(function() { location.reload(true); });
        });
    });
```

thanks @danielepolencic for link to [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Answer (score 2):

As someone already pointed out, this is an ajax call and doesn't resolve immediately. Without digging into much details, you can use the `done` method to execute some code when the `getJSON` returns the data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.quantityInput', function () {
        var data = {
            Id: $(this).data('index'),
            value: $(this).val()
        };
        $.getJSON("/Order/BasketSession/", data).done(function(){
          location.reload(true);
          console.log("hi!");
        });
    });
});
```

This works because `getJSON` return a promise for an event that will happen in the future. You can find more info about `getJSON` and promises [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).